# Which is faster c++ vector or python list

Tags: python, c++, list, vector

1. Created a vector of 10000 elements initialized to 5 and calculated time using chrono.

```
        auto startTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
        vector<int> v(10000, 5);
        for(auto& a : v)
                a *= a;
        auto stopTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(stopTime - startTime);
        cout<<"time: "<<duration.count()*1000<<" microsec\n";              //98362000 microsec
```

2. Created a list of 10000 elements initialized to 5.

```
from datetime import datetime
start = datetime.now()
a = [5]*10000
a = [a ** 2 for a in a]
end = datetime.now()
diff = end - start
print("time: ", diff.microseconds , " microseconds")      //1542 microseconds
```

From above it looks python is clear winner, but being c++ lower level(as i feel) why its slow wrt python?

I know time calculation algorithms by chrono and datetime package may different, But still what's the benchmark for comparing for vectors(c++) and lists(python)?

Comment: //98362000 microseconds, 98 seconds? Are you sure?

Comment: To convert from nanoseconds to microseconds you need to divide by 1000, not multiply. Your C++ code actually took much less time than your Python code.

Comment: Make sure you test a optimized release build, not a unoptimized debug build.

Comment: Note that a C++ compiler may fully remove your entire code, since it doesn't do anything meaningful. The execution time may be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C++ time calculation is incorrect. Since you want microsends you should ask for them directly instead of the calculation you have now. This is simpler and correct:

```
auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stopTime - startTime);
cout << "time: " << duration.count() << " microsec\n";
```

[Demo on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/qfE7hr)

Note: be sure you're testing an optimized build for useful results.

Comment: Thanks But is is good to compare time outputs by chrono and datetime package?